# Dynamic Web page

Tags: php, html, css

I followed this guide to create dynamic web page with PHP. But for some reason when I try to navigate to one of the pages I get an error message: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.`enter code here`

MY index.php

```
<title>Dynamic WebSite With PHP</title>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face
{
    src:url(asset/font.otf);
    font-family: myfont;
}
#uni
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px%;
    font-family: myfont;

}
#header
{
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white; 
    background: #a8480c;
}
#menubar
{
    width: 100%;
    background:#1f1a16;

}
#menubar a
{
    font-size: 24px;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;

}
#menubar a:hover
{
    color: #727272;
    background: white;
}
#footer
{
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    color: white;
    background:#1f1a16;
    font-size: 24px;

}
#content
{
    width: 96%;
    padding: 2%;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 500px;

}
</style>
<div id="uni">
<?php 
include('header.php');
?>
<div id="content">
    <?php
      if(isset($_GET['page'])) 
      {
        $page= $_GET['page'];
        $display=$page.'.php';
        include($display);
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'Hi, Welcome to my page! ';
      };
    ?>

</div>
<?php 
include('footer.php');
?>
</div>
```

And my header.php:

```
<div id='header'>Header</div>

<div id="menubar">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="index?page=about">About</a>
    <a href="index?page=downloads">Downloads</a>
    <a href="index?page=contact">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give an example of a url which should have worked but didn't?

Comment: I'm using xmapp and is just a localhost/index.php im using. that work, but if click on the navigation bar "about" "Downloads" or "Contact us" i get the error  message.

so E.g. if i click "About" the url is like this : http://localhost/index?page=about

Comment: Ok. Just to make sure, the pages "about.php" and "Downloads.php" do exist right?

Comment: yes, i have all of these files in the same folder as index.php. atm, there is only text in there atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.php` extension in header.php:

```
<div id='header'>Header</div>

<div id="menubar">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=about">About</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=downloads">Downloads</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```